# What is the best practice to get the width of a React component after it's been resized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, resizable

I have a resizable button, and need to get the width as soon as it's been resized:

```
useEffect(() => {
      if (myRef.current) setButtonWidth(myRef.current.offsetWidth);
    }, [myRef.current?.offsetWidth]);
```

This works as it should, getting the width after every resize, but it's my understanding that it's an anti-pattern to put a ref in a useEffect like this?

What would be the best practice to go about getting the width of the component after each resize?

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of a dom element using a `ref` is completely okay. However, using a [Resize Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) would be a more canonical way to track an element's size.

Comment: I tried that route, but was having trouble getting it to update on each resize. I'm sure i could've configured it probably though. Thank you for the response.